# Concatenate 2 arrays

Tags: powershell, csv

I have data in 2 arrays like below

```
$csvCreate:

Server Names Services Name
------------ --------------
abc           mn
123           OK
$csvCreate1:

Server Names Mounts  
------------ ------  
abc          OK      
123          /etc/999
```

Need to append the data in csv like below

```
Server Names Services Name Mounts  
------------ ------------- -------  
abc            mn            OK      
123            OK           /etc/999
```

Tried doing :

```
   $csvCreate = $csvCreate | Select-Object ServerName,Services
   $csvCreate1 = $csvCreate1 | Select-Object Mounts
   $finalData = $csvCreate +$csvCreate1
   $finalData | Export-Csv -Path $path\ComparedServicess.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But doesn't seems to be working.

Please let me know what i am missing here

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: It's in powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done that using below code

```
$JoinedObject = Foreach ($row in $csvCreate)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Servername = $row.ServerName
        Services     = $row.Services
        Mounts    = $csvCreate1 | Where-Object {$_.Servername -eq $row.Servername} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mounts
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are identical number of rows in each list and they are in same order, simple `for` loop would do:

```
$finalData = $csvCreate | Select-Object *, Mounts

for ($i=0; $i -lt $finalData.length; $i++) {
    $finalData[$i].Mounts = $csvCreate1[$i].Mounts
}
```